# Laravel LdapRecord array

Tags: php, laravel, active-directory, ldap, laravel-livewire

in a Lravel project I am working on to learn Laravel I am using the following:

- PHP v7.4.3
- Laravel v8.12.3
- Livewire v2.3.1
- directorytree/ldaprecord v1.12.0

After querying the directory, I am getting back an array that looks like his:

```
LdapRecord\Query\Collection {#1403 ▼
 #items: array:5 [▼
   0 => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\Entry {#1405 ▼
     +exists: true
     #dn: "CN=John Doe,DC=amce,DC=local"
     #in: null
     #connection: null
     #guidKey: "objectguid"
     #modifications: []
     #original: array:85 [▶]
     #attributes: array:85 [▼
       "objectclass" => array:4 [▶]
       "cn" => array:1 [▼
         0 => "John Doe"
       ]
       "sn" => array:1 [▶]
       "c" => array:1 [▶]
       "l" => array:1 [▶]
       "title" => array:1 [▶]
       "description" => array:1 [▶]
       ...
     ]
     #dates: []
     #casts: []
     #dateFormat: null
     #defaultDates: array:2 [▶]
     #hidden: []
     #visible: []
   }
   1 => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\Entry {#1406 ▶}
   2 => LdapRecord\Models\ActiveDirectory\Entry {#1407 ▶}
   ...
 ]
}
```

How do I access the active directory attributes of the users in the livewire component (for example cn or title)?
I want to be able to display the users as a searchable table and maybe in the future add crud functionality to that.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->getFirstAttribute('cn')
```

I'm using laravel 8 and that worked for me.

And below I'm showing you how I am getting the groups.

```
$user = Auth::user();
 $groups = Auth::user()->memberof;
```